# Django how to get username in models.py?

Tags: python, django, function, models

I need to get username in my models.py file

this part of model:

```
X = models.FileField(max_length=255, upload_to=get_upload_file_name, blank=True)
```

calls this function:

```
def get_upload_file_name(instance, filename):
    return "uploaded_files/%s_%s" % (str(time()).replace('.','_'), filename)
```

but I would like to add username to the filename. Could anyone suggest me how do i request username and get as a string in this case?

UPDATE:

```
@login_required
def addnew(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = PForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()   

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/all')

    else:
        form = PForm()

    args = {'full_name': request.user.username}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    args['form'] = form

    return render(request, 'addnew.html', args)
```

Comment: Could you post the whole model instead of just a field?

Comment: The easiest way would be being able to reach it from the `instance` if you are binding the file to the user probably you are also storing this in the model somehow. If this is not the case I think that you will need to customize the field or at least the `Model.save` method.

Comment: Agree with the others, instance probably holds a username field. If not, you can post us the view which calls the form.save() or model.save() and we might be able to help you from there.

Comment: hello @Josephjun.Melettukunnel i have update question with view :)

Answer (score 3):

The first parameter of `get_upload_file_name`, `instance` is the model instance the file belongs to, if that model has a `username` field, you can simply access this way: `instance.username`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your update, following code in your `views.py` should allow you to pass the username before calling save() on the object:

```
...
if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.YOUR_FILE_FIELD = obj.get_upload_file_name(request.user, filename)
        obj.save() 
...
```

Note that `form.save(commit=False)` will return you an object, which is not saved to the DB yet (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)

The `get_upload_file_name`method on the model itself needs to be updated like this:

```
def get_upload_file_name(username, filename):
    return "uploaded_files/%s_%s_%s" % (username, str(time()).replace('.','_'), filename)
```